# Is there a better approach to count SArray values?

Tags: python, list, counter, graphlab

I am looking for a better way to count the array values than what I have described below (Graphlab Create with Python)

```
labels = graphlab.SArray([-1, -1, 1, 1, 1])

plus_ones_count = list(labels).count(1)
# plus_ones_count outputs 3

minu_ones_count = list(labels).count(-1)
# minu_ones_count outputs 2
```

### Thank you for any pointers or suggestions.

After additional experiments len(labels[labels == ]) seems to be doing a better job (for my requirement where the desired number range is small) Just for others reference I am providing the code I used to measure three approaches. If you know any other better way of doing it (or) caveats please let me know.

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from collections import Counter

for data_set_size in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    labels = graphlab.SArray([randint(-1,1) for p in range(0, data_set_size)])
    print "Data set size: ", data_set_size

    %timeit -n 100 l = list(labels); l.count(-1), l.count(0), l.count(1)
    %timeit -n 100 len(labels[labels == -1]), len(labels[labels == 0]), len(labels[labels == 1])
    %timeit -n 100 label_count = Counter(labels); label_count.get(-1), label_count.get(0), label_count.get(1)
```

Comment: If you only have two values in the array, you don't need to count a second time.

Comment: Thanks Moses. The code snippet is simplified. Actual case would contain few thousands of data with any integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter from collections

```
labels = [-1, -1, 1, 1, 1]
from collections import Counter
label_count = Counter(labels)
label_count.get(1)
```

> 3

```
label_count.most_common()
```

> [(1, 3), (-1, 2)]

Ref link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Thanks Vikash - But I am looking for a better approach with SArray data type of Graphlab. Somehow it is not obvious for me from their API documents.

Comment: @SaravananChidambaram I don't think SArray has the Counter feature. Can't you convert your SArray to list and do the Counter computation?

Comment: Vikash: I did some additional experiments comparing 3 methods [1] The one converts SArray to list() and uses count() [2] Using access like len(labels[labels == -1]), which is what few seems to be using [3] Using Counter as you suggested. I limited the array values to {-1, 0, 1} with varying array size of 10 numbers to a million.You may be interested to know that Method #2 outperformed among the three as size increases. However I haven't experimented with any integer value instead of limiting to 3 values as in the case here.

Comment: Method 2 might have better performance because you counted for only 1 number. Where as method 3 does counting for all unique values in the list. But I agree with you. It's just that I don't optimise until I have to. 2 sec for millions or 10 sec does not make a difference. Only when it gets to exponential times like minutes or days do I start optimisation. Personal style. Premature optimisation is not my style. Neither is complicating code for optimisation. Just stating my views :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple hack I used.

```
plus_one_count = labels.where(labels == 1, 1, 0).sum()

#plus_one_count = graphlab.SArray.where(labels == 1, 1, 0).sum()

minu_ones_count = labels.where(labels == -1, 1, 0).sum()
```

It's just returning an SArray with 1 where the condition is True and zero otherwise, and then sums it up.

You can find the documentation for this  [here](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SArray.where.html).

Hope this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Source

```
labels = graphlab.SArray([-1, -1, 1, 1, 1])
print (labels == -1).nnz()
print (labels == 1).nnz()
```

Output

```
2
3
```

Links

https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SArray.nnz.html